# Are there any POS workstations which allow for customization of an application?

Tags: point-of-sale

I am evaluating Radiant POS workstations to see how easy it is to develop a customized POS application. I am looking for RAD Rapid Application Development without the need to code in Java or some other 3GL.

Comment: I don't understand why you tagged this with Java and C# if you want a POS workstation that *does not* require you to use them ...

Comment: because C# has a very wide audience of which I'm sure there are several who have experience with POS app development.